# ubuntu MALLOC_ARENA_MAX default value

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, memory, memory-leaks

How to see the default value of MALLOC_ARENA_MAX?
I want to change its value, and after testing change it back.
Although I have found out that its default value is `defaults to 8 * cpu_count`,but I want to use a command or from a config file to confirm it.

Comment: The value used defaults to `8 * cpu_count` and can be overridden by setting the variable `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX`.  So not the variable has a default value; it overrides a built-in default value.  You can find that mechanic of the default somewhere deeply hidden in the glibc sources.

Comment: How about setting it to `8 * cpu_count` (e. g. by `export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=$(( 8 * $(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) ))`) and then perform some tests; they should show no differences to the case of not setting the variable.

Comment: @Alfe thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I upvoted your comment! Are there any docs that give this information or source code you could point me to? I'm writing an article and I want to point to an authoritative source. Also do you know which `cpu_count` it uses?

Comment: Actually, looks like it's in the man page? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html